# Cancel redirect / beforeUnload

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cancel-button

I'm using [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin to display some nice ("Please wait...") message every time user changes URL, clicks link, is redirected, goes somewhere etc.:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){$.blockUI();});
```

Now, I'd like to enhance this message with a `Cancel` button, that would prevent such redirect and let user stay on current page. This leads me to a question: *Is there any way in Javascript to stop URL change process, that is in progress?* Or any other method/solution, that I could bind in this `Cancel` button's click event?

Am I trying to do something stupid or useless?

Comment: So can you confirm exactly what you want to happen
You want in the short amount of time that the old page is being displayed, for a button to appear that ***could*** cancel the url change.  But not actually prevent it from happening otherwise...
For most users the unload time will be less than a second which is no where near enough time to give them the option of clicking cancel?

Please explain again :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the beforeunload bit but what you are wanting to do is not technically supported by browser for security reasons.  Image the implications of an unclosable window...

The best thing to do is use the built in syntax.  Returning a string to `beforeunload` pops up a dialog box asking if you are sure you want to quit, with that string as the question and the options "leave page" or "stay on page".

Example

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return "Do you really want to leave this page?";
});
```

**UPDATE**

After further reading on this it turns out that major browsers support the return string syntax but Firefox does not.  Firefox will simply replace your string with the line "Are you sure you want to exit this page?" or something like that.

TLDR: You can use the above return string syntax in all browsers but your custom sentence won't be shown in Firefox :)

Comment: +1 for attempt of answering, but either I'm missing something or we're talking about two different things. Returning a string on `beforeunload` causes (if I'm not mistaken) to display a standard **modal** dialog with my string (except Firefox! :]). Since it is modal, page/URL change will not occur until user agrees. That's something I don't want at all. I want to prevent URL change, only if user clicks `Cancel` (it, what I want to do, is possible at all). But if he/she do nothing, normal URL change should occur. Displaying standard `beforeunload` question window will prevent that.